# Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qwebengineview

Hi. I want to connect QtWebEngineWidgets. To do this, you need to write(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-module.html) in .cpp file

```
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>
```

and

```
QT += webenginewidgets
```

inside **.pro** file.

The problem is that when writing to a .pro file, I get the error - ***Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets***

Everywhere I read, it is only written that you need to connect the module in the **.pro** file, but it doesn’t work for me. Am I doing everything right?

**• Qt Creator version - 5.0.0 Community**

**• Qt version - 6.1.3**

**• C++ compiler version - MSVC2019 64bit 17.032112.339(amd64)**

**UPD:**
I want to add that this module is not in the installer.

[Installer exaple1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKnzB.png), [Installer example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9xdR.png)

Comment: qt6.1.3 has no module qtwebenginewidgets?try qt 6.2.2?

Comment: @kenash0625, yes, it looks like it. Installing now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was necessary to install a newer version of Qt. For example, since *version 6.2.3.0 and newer*, the installer contains the *"WebView"* item. I'm installing it now and I'll see if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @gremeat, had the same problem. It is solved with `Qt Maintenance Tool`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the needed files aren't installed. Try adding this package containing the development files:

```
sudo apt-get install qtwebengine5-dev
```